# DocuSign integration from desktop application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, docusignapi

I am trying to implement document signing with the DocuSign API in our Windows desktop application built in VC++.

Our application is built with unmanaged code without using .net. I tried the supported languages, C++ is not available so I tried C# that is web interface which I can't use inside my application.

How can I use the DocuSign API in an unmanaged c++ application?

Comment: *What is the best way to do this?* -- Questions worded with "best way" can be closed for being opinion-based.  Then there is closing the question for lack of clarity.

Comment: What have you tried?  You're supposed to make _some_ kind of attempt before posting here.

Comment: Our application is built with unmanaged code without using .net. I tried the supported languages, C++ is not available so I tried C# that is web interface which I can't use inside my application.

Comment: *How can I use the DocuSign API* -- Then I suggest you get or hire someone who knows at least one of the supported languages very well, knows C++ very well, thus can build the C++ bindings to the API.  Also, from looking at the documentation [here](https://developers.docusign.com/sample-apps/), I don't think this is tied to .NET.  It is probably just that they created a .NET component for use with C#.  I see that Java is supported, and that is not a .NET language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft open-source REST API C++ SDK
https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk
"
C++ Rest SDK
[The C++ REST SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/index.html) is a Microsoft project for cloud-based client-server communication in native code using a modern asynchronous C++ API design. This project aims to help C++ developers connect to and interact with services."

You will still need to get an integration key and set it up for authentication, maybe use JWT since it's a desktop app.